Write a single query from multiple queries in MongoDB
I have 2 collections users and files. A user document looks like this :
{
  "_id": "user1",
  "name": "John"
}

A file document looks like this :
{
  "_id": "fileID1",
  "url": "any_url",
  "userID": "user1"
}

I have a list of user IDs let's say : ["user1", "user2", "user5"] and i want to perform a single query that takes this list as input and returns 5 files of each user ID.
For now i have a naive logic that is not really performant :
result_users = users_collection.find({}).limit(15)
  for user in result_users:
    user_id.append(user["_id"])
    result_files = files_collection.find({"userID": user["_id"]}).limit(5)
      for f in result_files:
        file_dict[user["_id"]].append(f)

The query i am looking for would naively be something like :
result_files = files_collection.find({"userID": {"$in / $each": user_ids_list}).limit(5)
The output i am looking for is :
{
  "user1": ["fileID1", "fileID2", "fileID8", "fileID3"],
  "user2": ["fileID4", "fileID5", "fileID6", "fileID9", "fileID7"],
  ...
}

With at max 5 files per userID.
I am pretty sure this is achievable with aggregation but i have no clue how to write it correctly.
Note : i don't really care about the output format, i only need a list of file that is sorted correctly with 5 files per userID.
I can map the output myself when i am confident the query returns the right files.
Thanks !
Edit : it would be amazing to add a sort("at", DESCENDING) on the files collection aggregation

yes sure the list of user ids is already available and the users collection is not needed here, it was for the example

https://mongoplayground.net/p/mGF103-pYqT probably this one but not in the object notation you need. will need more stages for that . https://mongoplayground.net/p/9B6ciQxJTj-

you are totally right the sorting order is by date descending on the files. thanks for the links i am looking into them

This is exactly the output i am looking for ! But indeed can you add a "at" field on the file object and sort descending by "at" please ? at is the millisecondsSinceEpoch value in my collection but you can use incremental values for testing. Thank you very much anyway

i composed an answer out of the comments

since you already have the user names in the file docs you won't need to query user collection.

First narrow down the files using a $match based on existence of user in input array
Group by the userID field and push the file id and the timestamp (will need later for sorting)
Now call $sortArray on the grouped file array (v). Now it is sorted in descending(-1). On that sorted call $slice and finally map over the sliced array to get an array of just the ids.
this will now generate in the format [ { _id:"user1",v: [...]}, { _id:"user2",v: [...]}... ]

db.files.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { userID: { $in: ["user1", "user2", "user5"] } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userID",
      v: { $push: { id: "$_id", at: "$at" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      v: {
        $map: {
          input: { $slice: [{ $sortArray: { input: "$v", sortBy: { at: -1 } } }, 5] },
          in: "$$this.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])


playground
if you want to further convert it to { "user1": [...], "user2": [...], ... } format you can add these 2 stages
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      kv: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$v" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$kv" } }
  }


playground

thank you very much it's working fine !

One last thing @cmgchess, you did : v: { $push: { id: "$_id", at: "$at" } }
but is there any way to $push the whole document instead of some fields ? i have seen the $$ROOT but it seems to be server side, not working in pymongo it returns None objects... I am going to push all fields one by one for now but just curious if there was something else ? Thanks anyway !

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author $$ROOT seems to be the way https://mongoplayground.net/p/RJlryvgPPuH

@Tom3652  a mongoplayground tip if you dont know already. there is a stage dropdown on top. you can view the result in between stages in the pipeline so u know what each stage actually tries to do

oh alright thank you i didn't know that indeed, and ok for $$ROOT even if it doesn't work for pymongo, will keep pushing all fields for now

hmm ROOT should work even work pymongo since its standard mongo syntax. are u sure its not something else. for example i had to change to in: "$$this._id" from in: "$$this.id" after introducing root

yes exactly it's working fine now i have discovered that as well ! now we speak about it, do you know how i can get the whole document fields as the output ? the syntax i have guessed so far is to list them : in: ['$$this._id', '$$this.at']

@Tom3652 in that case you can remove the whole $map altogether. the reason i put it is to extract the ids from each whole document. so rmoving it should do the trick https://mongoplayground.net/p/2oaYw5thaGD

perfect it works thank you very much for your help all along.

That's in JS, but I am sure in py you could do something like below:
const user_ids_list = ["user1", "user2", "user5"];

const result_files = await files_collection.aggregate([
  // Match files where userID is in the user_ids_list
  { 
    $match: { 
      userID: { $in: user_ids_list } 
    }
  },
  // Group by userID and collect up to 5 files per user
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: "$userID",
      files: { $push: "$_id" }
    }
  },
  // Limit to the first 5 files for each userID
  { 
    $project: { 
      files: { $slice: ["$files", 5] } 
    }
  }
]).toArray();

console.log(result_files);

This should give you an output similar to:
[
  { "_id": "user1", "files": ["fileID1", "fileID2", "fileID8", "fileID3", "fileID9"] },
  { "_id": "user2", "files": ["fileID4", "fileID5", "fileID6", "fileID7", "fileID10"] },
  ...
]


thanks for your reply, but @cmgchess was faster to answer and he added a sorting way despite this was not in my question in the first place it may help others to see where to position the sort function
